# Incorrect latitude-longitude positioning in ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

This problem came up [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465724/ggplot2-and-maps-geom-point-and-annotation-raster-position-mismatch), and as suggested here, it was [addressed](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/ABffHL3WTpY).  But it seems to have been only partially addressed.

First, here is code that works, showing a dot approximately at the location of the White House:

```
require(ggmap)
gc = geocode('the white house')
qmap(location = "the white house", maptype = "roadmap", zoom = 3) +
   geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = gc, color="red", size = 3)
```

However, if I change `maptype` to `"toner"`, which I prefer for its simplicity and clarity of state boundaries, the White House goes north, well into Canada:

```
qmap(location = "the white house", maptype = "toner", zoom = 3) +
   geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = gc, color="red", size = 3)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a bug , but You can set location as numeric (lat,long) using geocde , you gc variable.

Comment: I notice that I can get some of the simplicity without using `toner` by setting `color = "bw"` in `qmap`.