# How to prevent ggmap (with Stamen maps) from misaligning points and features latitudes at low zoom?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

When using ggmap, Stamen maps and continental-level zooms (zoom=3), the point-latitudes do not align with the map. For example:

```
library(ggmap)
gc <- geocode('the white house')

qmap('the white house', zoom = 3) + # looks good
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = gc, colour = 'red')

qmap('the white house', zoom = 3, source = 'stamen', maptype="toner") + # not so good
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = gc, colour = 'red')
```

This seems to have been and [addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465724/ggplot2-and-maps-geom-point-and-annotation-raster-position-mismatch) defect for googlemaps and osm maps - what strategies can I employ to work-around for Stamen?

Comment: If I were you, I would send a message to the package author in this case.

Comment: @schnee did you report this to the ggmap owner?

Comment: @geotheory - I have not. I was going to and found this is already an issue on github: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/32

so I starred it