# ggmap stamen map accuracy glitch

Tags: r, ggmap

ggmap appears to be handling map tiles from Google and stamen inconsistently, at least at global scale.  Stamen is the problem.  The following code illustrates.

```
require(ggplot2); require(ggmap)
m_google = get_map(location = c(-.2, 51.5), zoom=3)
m_stamen = get_map(location = c(-.2, 51.5), zoom=3, source = "stamen", maptype = "toner")

ggmap(m_google, extent = 'panel') + geom_point(data=NULL, aes(-.2, 51.5), col='red', size=5)
ggmap(m_stamen, extent = 'panel') + geom_point(data=NULL, aes(-.2, 51.5), col='red', size=5)
```

Glitch?

[image]

Comment: slight problem in your `d=data.frame...` line, it doesn't parse as is.. but then you don't use it in your example anyway do you?

Comment: also, my stamen map seems to be more zoomed in, I don't get any of Greenland and only a bit of Africa and no Russia... which versions are you on here?

Comment: @Spacedman - yes d is redundant please ignore.  Pics are at zoom=3, but same effect visible at zoom=4.

Comment: yes, I get a red dot not in the right place. QGIS seems to register stamen tiles in the right lat-long so I reckon its a ggmap bug.

Comment: Looks covered in SO [just recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588244/how-to-prevent-ggmap-with-stamen-maps-from-misaligning-points-and-features-lat). Didn't spot that.